# ML: Are the majority of models in R's Caret available in Python?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, r-caret

R's Caret clearly supports a wide range of models that are accessible by simply changing `method`:

```
fit <- caret::train(y = as.vector(y), 
                      x = x, 
                      method = BstLm, 
                      trControl = ctrl,
                      preProc = c("center", "scale"))
```

Are most of the models in the caret list below available in Python (through scikit-learn or otherwise)?

https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html

For example, I wanted to implement the  Boosted Linear Model method = 'BstLm' in Python, but couldn't find any way, certainly not a way as simply changing one variable in caret.

Comment: Are you looking for http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html ? Not too familiar with that specific model. One of the little advantages of R is that it sometimes gets lesser known or newer models, but this one seems common enough.

Comment: Going back to caret, the goal of caret is to give you good implementations of good models, so the really obscure ones you can find for R are less likely in caret. Therefore, the models in caret are exactly the sort that are also probably available in Python.

Comment: @JoshRumbut I think there is a difference between gradient boost regressor (which you cite) and boosted linear model: https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/BstLm.R

Comment: You're quite right, my mistake.